# Why use a pointer when using a custom http.Handler in Go?

Tags: pointers, go, methods, interface

When calling `http.Handle()` in the code snippet below, I'm using my own `templateHandler` type which implements the `http.Handler` interface.

```golang
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "path/filepath"
    "sync"
)

type templateHandler struct {
    once     sync.Once
    filename string
    templ    *template.Template
}

func (t *templateHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t.once.Do(func() {
        t.templ = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(filepath.Join("templates", t.filename)))
    })
    t.templ.Execute(w, nil)
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", &templateHandler{filename: "chat.html"})
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

Now for some reason I have to pass a pointer to `http.Handle()` using `&templateHandler{filename: "chat.html"}`. Without the `&` I get the following error:

```
cannot use (templateHandler literal) (value of type templateHandler) 
as http.Handler value in argument to http.Handle: 
missing method ServeHTTP
```

Why exactly is this happening? What difference does using a pointer make in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`http.Handle()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handle) expects a value (any value) that implements [`http.Handler`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler), which means it must have a `ServeHTTP()` method.

You used pointer receiver for the `templateHandler.ServeHTTP()` method, which means only a pointer value to `templateHandler` has this method, but not that of a non-pointer `templateHandler` type.

[Spec: Method sets:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)

> A type may have a *method set* associated with it. The method set of an [interface type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) is its interface. The method set of any other type `T` consists of all [methods](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations) declared with receiver type `T`. The method set of the corresponding [pointer type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types) `*T` is the set of all methods declared with receiver `*T` or `T` (that is, it also contains the method set of `T`).

A non-pointer type only has methods with non-pointer receivers. A pointer type has methods both with pointer and non-pointer receivers.

Your `ServeHTTP()` method modifies the receiver, so it must be a pointer. But if some other handler does not need to, the `ServeHTTP()` method may be created using a non-pointer receiver, and in that case you can use a non-pointer value as the `http.Handler`, like in this example:

```
type myhandler struct{}

func (m myhandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {}

func main() {
    // non-pointer struct value implements http.Handler:
    http.Handle("/", myhandler{})
}
```